# if/elseif command not working properly

Tags: matlab

Dear StackOverflow community,

As I've already experienced your willingness to help over and over again, I came here once more for help.

As of now, I have a simulator that contains "customers". I want to categorize them by assigning various customer types (as a property). Up to a certain point, this assignment works pretty fine but somehow, there's still a bug in my code. But see for yourself:

## Main function

```
ncust = 500 %//(number of customers)

%function call

for ii = 1:ncust;
    customers{ii} = Customer(ii);
    customers{ii}.setcustTypeDistrib(ncust);
end
```

Each customer has a property called "id" (customer 1 has id 1 -> who would've guessed that?)

## Class customer

```
function obj = setcustTypeDistrib(obj, ncust) %sets types of customers
    if obj.id < ceil(ncust/2) % 50 percent of the customers are type 1
        obj.custType = 1;

    elseif ceil(ncust/2) < obj.id || obj.id < ceil(0.75*ncust)
        obj.custType = 2;

    elseif ceil(0.76*ncust) < obj.id 
        obj.custType = 3;
    end
end
```

However, if I check, for example, customer 450 (in MATLAB: `customers{450}`) he is customer type 2 although he should be customer type 3. What am I doing wrong? I feel completely lost!

---

## Edit for example

Customer with properties:

```
id: 490
custType: 2
minInterval: 4.7846e+04
```

Comment: I didn't intend to offend anyone and I most certainly didn't consider that I could do so by insulting myself. However, I'll edit my post accordingly :) Thanks for your hint!

Comment: No prob, I'll remove the above comment so no one else has to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are using an 'or' statement in `ceil(ncust/2) < obj.id || obj.id < ceil(0.75*ncust)` so because of `ceil(ncust/2) < obj.id`everything with an object id over half will be type two. Use an 'and' statement and you'll get the desired result.

e.g.

`ceil(ncust/2) < obj.id && obj.id < ceil(0.75*ncust)`